# process.env.PORT and app

Tags: iis, iisnode

What on earth is happening with process.env.PORT???

**IISnode log reports**:
1.process.env.PORT:  \.\pipe\294dc919-9aab-44a1-8cfa-750b1d520586
2. running server on process.env.PORT:  \.\pipe\294dc919-9aab-44a1-8cfa-750b1d520586

**node.js console.log reports:**
1.process.env.PORT:  undefined
2. running server on process.env.PORT:  undefined

**These URLs run correctly:**
domain.com:80/index.html
domain.com:otherPortNumber/index.html

**This URL returns error 404 - File or Directory not found:**
domain.com

Any one has any idea what is going on. I'd love to hear from you. 
I imagine i am not the only one with this problem!!!

Thank you.